# Вывод символов char16_t и char32_t

Tags: c++, c++11, char

Объект `wcout` в C++ отображает только числовые значения литералов типов `char16_t` и `char32_t`. Что нужно сделать, чтобы вывести в консоль символьные значения данных типов?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого в стандарт нужно добавить потоки вывода для данных типов. На данный момент подобной возможности в C++ нет.

В настоящий момент, если консоль поддерживает utf-8, можно преобразовать исходные символы в utf-8 и вывести их.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразовав в wchar_t:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char16_t v = 42;
    std::wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(v) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```